# Why Todo List in React erases always the last item?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been trying to make a Todo List App Work with React Hooks.

Everything works just fine when I use `<span>{todo}</span>`. It just delete the element that I click. But when I change `<span>{todo}</span>` for `<input></input>`, every 'X' that I click to delete always delete the last element. I just don't know what's happening, as the keys aren't changed.

Todo.js Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TodoForm = ({ saveTodo }) => {
  const[value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        saveTodo(value);
        setValue('');
      }}
    >
      <input onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)} value={value} />
    </form>
  )
}


const TodoList =({ todos, deleteTodo }) => (
  <ul>
    {
      todos.map((todo, index) => (
        <li key={index.toString()}>
          <span>{todo}</span>
          <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(index)}>X</button>
        </li>
      ))
    }
  </ul>
);


const Todo = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Todos</h1>

      <TodoForm saveTodo={todoText => {
        const trimmedText = todoText.trim();

        if(trimmedText.length > 0) {
          setTodos([...todos, trimmedText]);
        }
      }} 
    />
      <TodoList 
        todos={todos}
        deleteTodo={todoIndex => {
          const newTodos = todos.filter((_, index) => index !== todoIndex);
          setTodos(newTodos);
        }} 
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

It changes the deletion behavior when I change:

```
<li key={index.toString()}>
  <span>{todo}</span>
  <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(index)}>X</button>
</li>
```

to:

```
<li key={index.toString()}>
  <input></input>
  <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(index)}>X</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is the case? Or it just seems to behave that way, because you render the input without any values? If I paste your code (and adjust the input to actually include the value of the todo) into a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-bush-x2o7k) it deletes the correct element. Please also consider that using indexes as list keys should be seen as the "last resort" (See [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `index` as the key. Therefore the last item (`key` that stops existing) is removed and all the other items are just updated.

Instead, create some kind of unique `id` for your todos and use that `id` as `key`.

Comment: But why when I change to <span> it does not happen?